# Apache 2.4 - Simple reverse proxy - not working for multiple entries

Tags: linux, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

I referred the below link and configured the  proxy.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

When I configure a proxy for a single application as below in Apache 2.4 in the `httpd.conf` file, the proxy configuration is working fine. I am able to access my application through the proxy server URL.

```
ProxyPass / http://host1:8888/
ProxyPassReverse / http://host1:8888/
```

However If I try configure for two application like below, I am not able to access any of the application.

```
ProxyPass /nifi http://host1:8888/
ProxyPassReverse /nifi http://host1:8888/

ProxyPass /kibana http://host2:5601/
ProxyPassReverse /kibana http://host2:5601/
```

Comment: I also tried with placing them in double quotes as well... It is still not working....

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how you try to reach the application makes it difficult to guess what's might be wrong.
I suggest you to change the proxies config as following:

```
ProxyPass /nifi/ http://host1:8888/
ProxyPassReverse /nifi/ http://host1:8888/

ProxyPass /kibana/ http://host2:5601/
ProxyPassReverse /kibana/ http://host2:5601/
```

then try to reach the endpoint pointing your browser to http://youdomain/nifi/ and http://youdomain/kibana/ and check the logs for errors.